# Clarifying the interface tag

Tags: discussion, tags

“Interface” is a very broad word that could mean anything. The [interface](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interface) tag is mostly about network interfaces, and the questions are mostly about Ethernet interfaces.

We have an [ethernet](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ethernet) tag for questions specifically about Ethernet transport and interfaces. However some questions may warrant a more generic tag [network-interface](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/network-interface).

Should we use [network-interface](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/network-interface)? Are there other kinds of interfaces that warrant a tag?

Comment: I also see from time to time people using interface as a synonym for GUI

Answer (score 2):

I find that is not a bad idea, creating [network-interface](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/network-interface), through we should verify what kind of questions should use the tag. I think that [interface](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interface) itself should be deleted as I can't find anyone really [answering those questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/interface/topusers), nor I have any idea what kind of questions I expect of them.

Comment: the creation of [tag:network-interface] implies the creation [tag:serial-interface] [tag:usb-interface] and so one....

Comment: @Kiwy Why create [tag:serial-interface]? What distinction do you see with [tag:serial-port], and what questions would benefit from that tag? We create tags to classify questions, not just for the sake of creating tags.